# Ignore deprecated methods with python coverage testing

Tags: python, python-decorators, coverage.py

I am doing some coverage analyis on a code base that contains a fair amount of deprecated (using [the deprecated package](https://pypi.org/project/Deprecated/)) methods.

Most of these deprecated methods do not have any tests. So when doing a code coverage analysis (using [coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/)) these methods greatly pollute the results and make it hard to identify the important uncovered areas.

I know that I can manually add `#pragma: no cover` to these methods to ignore them. However, since they already have that decorator, I was curious if I could automatically filter these cases, for examply by using something similar to `exclude_lines =...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to define `exclude_lines` with a regex that matches the decorator, and it will apply to the decorated function:

```
[report]
exclude_lines = 
    pragma: no cover
    @deprecated
```

(etc...)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I knew that you could match with the function name, but I didn't expect that to also hold for the decorators.

Comment: The `exclude_lines` setting are regexes used to match the text of lines. It doesn't care about the Python code in use at all.